# Limit the amount of RAM Mathematica may access?

Tags: performance-tuning, front-end, system-performance

Trying to solve a differential equation numerically, I noticed that Mathematica used up all RAM to the extent that my operating system (Windows 10) lost responsiveness and hung up.

As a result I had to restart my machine, losing all unsaved progress in the Mathematica notebook I was working on.

> Is there a way to limit the RAM amount Mathematica can possibly access during a calculation?

Comment: You can use [`MemoryConstrained`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MemoryConstrained) to constrain the amount of memory a computation takes.

Comment: @CarlWoll Thanks! I wonder if there is a setting that applies this to the entire kernel session?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [`MemoryConstrained`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MemoryConstrained) to set a memory constraint for an evaluation. You can use [`$Pre`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Pre) to set a memory constraint for all evaluations:

```
$Pre = Function[
    Null,
    MemoryConstrained[#, 2000000000-MemoryInUse[]],
    HoldAll
];
```

For example:

```
Range[10^9]
```

> $Aborted