# Limit the amount of RAM Mathematica can use and still get sensible results?

Tags: performance-tuning, system-performance

The question is very similar to [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/194878/limit-the-amount-of-ram-mathematica-may-access), however the solution proposed there doesn't satisfy me because I don't want Mathematica to abort the evalution, but simply to do it with less RAM.

Basically I'd like Mathematica to think my machine has for example only 14 Gb of RAM, let it use only those, and not abort the evaluation when it uses more than 14 Gb, like suggested there. I would like Mathematica to run as it would run in a virtual box which can only access 14 GB of RAM, but I don't want to use a virtual box

Is this possible?

If it is possible, can I trust the results obtained in this way or there's an high chance of losing important pieces during the evalution, due to the fact that mathematica would use more ram to perform that evaluation?

Comment: I don’t understand your point of view. When a certain amount of RAM is needed to fit a certain computation in memory, if the RAM is unavailable then the system can’t “make do with less”. It simply can’t do it. You, the programmer, will have to change your algorithm and come up with clever tricks to avoid high memory usage.

Comment: @MarcoB Ok thank you, I thought about this but I wasn't sure, that's why I asked the second part of the question. Sadly it's not my notebook and since I'm not a programmer I wouldn't know how to make it more efficient. 

Anyway, shouln't mathematica stop itself when it's using all the memory on my machine? By the logic that it can't do it with that amount of memory I'd think it should stop or that there would be some built in function that notices that it needs more ram but it's using all the ram of the machine and that would make it stop.

Comment: Yes such functionality exists. You can wrap the code that may use too much memory within [`MemoryConstrained`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MemoryConstrained.html). That would prevent MMA from gobbling up all your memory, but it would still abort the computation if the limit is reached.

Comment: @Thank you but I know about that since it is explained in the question I linked. Maybe I shoud rephrase, doesn't mathematica notices it is using all the RAM on my machine and can't go on without using more and then stop the computation? It happens with this notebook I'm running, it used all the 8 GB of RAM but it didn't abort, then I tried it with 16GB and it used them all aswell, and it would probably need more, but still didn't abort

Comment: Managing memory requests is up to the operating system. The operating system may answer to request for memory that exceed actual RAM by swapping data to disk, rather than just denying the request. “Although virtual memory allows you in principle to use large amounts of memory space, it is usually hundreds or even thousands of times slower to access than physical memory. As a result, if your calculation becomes so large that it needs to make use of virtual memory, it may run much more slowly.”

Comment: Ok, so is it possible, since mathematica is not aborting the computation, that the evaluation of the notebook is still going on, just slower? In this case I'd accept that that and patiently wait the time it requires.

How would I know it's using virtual memory? Can I simply trust the fact that since mathematica isn't crushing that the system gave it extra memory?

Comment: It is possible but, if swap is in use, it might slow down so much that it would practically never finish within a reasonable time...

Comment: @MarcoB ok, thank you for your help, I'll try to let it run for a night and see if it has finished for the morning.

Comment: @MarcoB   In my experience, sometimes the Windows operating system swaps Mathematica materials to disk when memory is about gone.  As you noted, this leads to an excruciatingly slow computation.  But, at other times Mathematica simply crashes.  I do not know what distinguishes between these two cases.  Perhaps, Mathematica tries to write to memory faster than Windows can free memory by swapping material to disk.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I (fortunately?) have little experience of exceeding memory limits as I rarely need that much memory in what I do. In those few cases when I have hit a memory limit, I quickly backed off and took another path :-)